# Why is this not a perfect square?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $x, y$ and $z$ be positive integers with $x<y$. It appears that the integer
$$(y^2z^3-x)(y^2z^3+3x)$$
is never a perfect square. Why? A proof? I'm not sure if it is easy.

Comment: Note: a "perfect square" and "perfect number" are two very different notions. You mean the former one here.

Comment: True. Corrected.

Comment: Looks like a hometask. Search for a square close to your number...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov This question is a corrected version of one previously asked by the OP, where he said that the original motivation was from some calculation in a real analysis problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite your expression as $(y^2z^3+x)^2-4x^2$. This is clearly less than $(y^2z^3+x)^2$. On the other hand, it is larger than $(y^2z^3+x-2)^2=(y^2z^3+x)^2-4(y^2z^3+x)+4$, since $4(y^2z^3+x)-4\geq 4y^2+4x-4\geq 4y^2>4x^2$. So if this expression is a square, it must be $(y^2z^3+x-1)^2=(y^2z^3+x)^2-2(y^2z^3+x)+1$, so $4x^2=2(y^2z^3+x)-1$. LHS is even, while RHS is odd, so this can't be.

Comment: Cute. Thanks. Actually it was easy then.